# Return series from specific value within pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to return a series that contains some addition from specific values in a pandas `df`. Specifically, for the `df` below. I want to add all the `X's` with all the `Y's`. These aren't in any specific order though.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Item' : ['X','Y','Z','X','Z','Y','Z'],                                     
    'Value' : [10,11,20,21,10,30,31],                                     
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

Xs = df.loc[df['Item'] == 'X', 'Value']
Ys = df.loc[df['Item'] == 'Y', 'Value']

Out = Xs + Ys
```

Intended Output:

```
21
51
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is problem different indices, so need same by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
Out = Xs.reset_index(drop=True) + Ys.reset_index(drop=True)
print (Out)
0    21
1    51
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Or if possible different length of `Series` use [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
Out = Xs.reset_index(drop=True).add(Ys.reset_index(drop=True), fill_value=0)
```

Or if always same length of `Series` is possible sum 1d numpy arrays:

```
Out = pd.Series(Xs.values + Ys.values)
print (Out)
0    21
1    51
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

I preferred @jezrael answer but I want to share my thought.

```
Xs = df.loc[df['Item'] == 'X', 'Value'].tolist()
Ys = df.loc[df['Item'] == 'Y', 'Value'].tolist()

Out = pd.Series(list(map(sum, zip(Xs, Ys))))

print(Out)
```